# PowerEdge 840 has blinking green light and does not startup

Tags: boot, power-supply, windows-server

I have a Dell PowerEdge 840 server. I powered it off using the start menu to perform a shutdown. Ever since I've done that, I cannot get it to power on again. The indicator light on the front of the server just continuously blinks green. I have a PS2 keyboard and mouse attached to it without a monitor. The power supply fan comes on, the CPU fan does not start, and I cannot ping the server. Does anyone have any ideas why it won't startup?

Comment: Likely the power supply is dead. Why don't you see a repairman?

Comment: A repairman would cost more than the machine is worth. I'm trying to power it on long enough to decommission it and then wipe it.

Comment: unplug it and confirm everything inside is seated correctly/nothing looks damaged. If you want to decommission it but can't fix your issues just pull the drives and wipe them in a different machine or have fun with a drill.

Comment: If you have some expertise, or have a friend that does, you could temporarily cannibalize other devices for the test. I would start with the power supply.

Comment: @mael - That's a great idea to pull the hard drives and wipe them separately. I'll definitely open it up and check things out. Thank you for the great ideas.

Comment: @harrymc - This is the only 840 the company has. I don't have another one I can cannibalize. That's an awesome idea though. I also don't want to buy any parts for this machine because it's not worth it. I'll give these great ideas a shot and let you guys know what happens.

Comment: You don't need another 840: Any other PSU can serve with enough capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending days on this issue, I found out that the power button was sticking. I had to press extremely hard on the button and hold it down in order for it to power on. Thank you to everyone who attempted to help me.